# "Yesterday I was fired from work, broke up with my girlfriend, and this morning, to cap it all off, lost my wallet."

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

Which sentence is more accurate

> Yesterday I was fired from work, broke up with my girlfriend, and this morning, to cap it all off, lost my wallet.

or

> Yesterday I was fired from work **and** broke up with my girlfriend, and this morning, to cap it all off, I lost my wallet.

Comment: It really is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The latter sentence is more correct. I would recommend splitting the events that happened yesterday into a different sentence, however:

> Yesterday, I was fired from work and I broke up with my girlfriend. This morning, to cap it all off, I lost my wallet.

The issue with the first is that the first two items in the list are qualified with "Yesterday" but the last is qualified with "This morning".

Comment: Yes, I mentioned the second was more correct. The first has the awkwardness of "Yesterday I did this, this, and this morning that." Not sure if that is explicitly wrong but it is more difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

> Yesterday I was fired from work, broke up with my girlfriend, and this morning, to cap it all off, lost my wallet.

or

> Yesterday I was fired from work and broke up with my girlfriend, and this morning, to cap it all off, I lost my wallet.

**Either one is fine.**

As are these:

> Yesterday, I left town, drove north, and this morning I arrived in Newport.

> Yesterday, I left town and drove north, and this morning I arrived in Newport.

There is absolutely no rule that says you can't have two predicates without an "and" and then an "and" and another predicate.

It just depends on how **you want to say it**.

The first is slightly more emphatic on the actions.

Answer (score 0):

In example 1, the sentence consists of 3 phrases in a series.

@Calmpalm is right that this is awkward as its first 2 phrases are qualified with ''yesterday'.

We can move in the 'yesterday', and the 3 phrases are now
subordinated to 'I'.

The reconstructed sentence is

'I was fired from work yesterday, broke up with my girlfriend, and this morning, to cap it all off, lost my wallet.'

Example 2 is a compound sentence.  Two simple sentences are compounded by the coordinating conjunction, the 2nd 'and'.
This is alright even without being split into 2 sentences.